# Why am I getting an error while implementing Implement Paging in asp.net gridview?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I get an error:

> The data source does not support server-side data paging.

in the `GVbind` method: `GridView.DataBind();`

Why do I get this error?

I faced this issue when I added display data method and page index changing

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MERIH-PC;Initial Catalog=aspidus;Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GVbind();
        }
    }

    void clear()
    {
        txtName.Text = "";
        txtPhone.Text = "";
        txtAdd.Text = "";
    }

    protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[idus] VALUES ('" + txtName.Text + "', '" + txtPhone.Text + "', '" + txtAdd.Text + "')", con);

        int t = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (t > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Data inserted successfully') </script>");
            con.Close();
        }

        GVbind();
        clear();
    }

    protected void GVbind()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[idus]", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows == true)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dr;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GVbind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        string name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
        string phone = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
        string address = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update [dbo].[idus] set name='" + name + "', phone='" + phone + "', address='" + address + "' where ID = '" + ID + "'", con);

        int t = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (t > 0)
        {
            con.Close();
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Data has been updated') </script>");
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            GVbind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GVbind();

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from [dbo].[idus] where ID='" + id + "'", con);

        int t = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (t > 0)
        {
            con.Close();
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Data has been deleted') </script>");
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            GVbind();
        }
    }

    protected void DisplayData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from [dbo].[idus]", con);

        con.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging1(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GVbind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's saying the `DataTable` does not support paging. Have you looked into using another type of data source?

Comment: no i didn't think about it but it says the problem is from the GVbind method. Before adding the DisplayData method and turning on the Allowpaging properties, my codes were working. after doing these i think there is a problem between DisplayData and GVbind

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)